# How does Skype gain access to port forwarding?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, skype

Whenever I go to my router's configuration > **NAT** > **Virtual Servers**, I see many entries titled *"Skype UDP at 10.0.0.X:< port> (< port>)"*. I believe that these are being made by the Skype client on different hosts, to allow some sort of functionality. How does Skype manage to get access to port-forwarding? Is there any way to disable this?

---

I have the Zyxel VMG1312-B30B router

Comment: Probably [Universal Plug and Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)

Comment: [SO] dupe: [How does Skype work without port forwarding?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1539339)

Comment: @DavidPostill My UPnP was activated. I will disable it and report if the Skype entries re-appear

Comment: Relevant: [What is the difference between UDP hole punching and UPnP?](http://superuser.com/q/617263)

Comment: @DavidPostill Every single Skype entry disappeared upon disabling UPnP. Please put the solution in an answer

Comment: Answer provided :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How does Skype manage to get access to port-forwarding?

> Is there any way to disable this?

One of the ways Skype gets arounhd firewalls is by using [Universal Plug and Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play).

You can disable UPnP in your router to prevent this.

See the links below for more information.

---

#### Further Reading

- [What is the difference between UDP hole punching and UPnP?](https://superuser.com/questions/617263)
- [How does Skype work without port forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539339)
- [How Skype Gets Round Firewalls](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747314.html)